# Azure Data Factory V2 - Input and Output

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to reproduce the following architecture based on the following github repo: https://github.com/Azure/cortana-intelligence-price-optimization

The problem is the part linked to the ADF, since in the guide it uses the old version of ADF: I don't know how to map in ADF v2 the "input" and "output" properties of a single activity so that they point to a dataset.

The pipeline performs a spark activity that does nothing more than execute a python script, and then I think it should write data into the dataset I defined already.

Here is the json of the ADF V1 pipeline inside the guide, which I cannot replicate:

```
    "activities": [
    {
      "type": "HDInsightSpark",
      "typeProperties": {
        "rootPath": "adflibs",
        "entryFilePath": "Sales_Data_Aggregation_2.0_blob.py",
        "arguments": [ "modelsample" ],
        "getDebugInfo": "Always"
      },
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "BlobStoreAggOutput"
        }
      ],
      "policy": {
        "timeout": "00:30:00",
        "concurrency": 1,
        "retry": 1
      },
      "scheduler": {
        "frequency": "Hour",
        "interval": 1
      },
      "name": "AggDataSparkJob",
      "description": "Submits a Spark Job",
      "linkedServiceName": "HDInsightLinkedService"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spark activity in a Data Factory pipeline executes a Spark program on your own or on-demand HDInsight cluster. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-spark) builds on the data transformation activities article, which presents a general overview of data transformation and the supported transformation activities. When you use an on-demand Spark linked service, Data Factory automatically creates a Spark cluster for you just-in-time to process the data and then deletes the cluster once the processing is complete.

Upload "Sales_Data_Aggregation_2.0_blob.py" to storage account attached to the HDInsight cluster and the modify the sample definition of a spark activity and create a schedule trigger and run the code:

Here is the sample JSON definition of a Spark activity:

```
 {
    "name": "Spark Activity",
    "description": "Description",
    "type": "HDInsightSpark",
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "MyHDInsightLinkedService",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "sparkJobLinkedService": {
            "referenceName": "MyAzureStorageLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "rootPath": "adfspark",
        "entryFilePath": "test.py",
        "sparkConfig": {
            "ConfigItem1": "Value"
        },
        "getDebugInfo": "Failure",
        "arguments": [
            "SampleHadoopJobArgument1"
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.